# laptop overheating after installing ubuntu

Tags: nvidia, intel, overheating

i have HP PAVILLON with intel core i7 10th generation and NVIDIA GeForce MX250 that word pretty well with windows 10, but after installing ubuntu 20.04 my laptop start heating for no reason, can you heap please

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you installed the graphic driver correctly and working fine. It happen to me the same situation but fixed after re installing the correct gpu driver.

You can refer this page : https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04/

Comment: i didn't. how do i install them??

Comment: Added a good link please check.

Comment: i still have the same problem